# How to have mixed datatypes values inside pyspark F.create_map

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using pyspark's `create_map` function to create a list of `key:value` pairs. My problem is that when I introduce key value pairs with string value, the key value pairs with float values are all converted to string!

Does anyone know how to avoid this happening?

To reproduce my problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("test").getOrCreate()

test_df = spark.createDataFrame(
    pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "key": ["a", "a", "a"],
            "name": ["sam", "sam", "sam"],
            "cola": [10.1, 10.2, 10.3],
            "colb": [10.2, 12.1, 12.1],
        }
    )
)

test_df.withColumn("test", F.create_map(
     F.lit("a"), F.col("cola").cast("float"), 
      F.lit("b"), F.col("colb").cast("float"),
      F.lit("key"), F.lit("default"),
      F.lit("name"), F.lit("ext"),
 )).show()
```

If you observe inside the mapping created... the values for `cola` and `colb` are strings, not floats!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. [`MapType`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datatypes.html) values must have the same type. The same applies for the keys.

> `MapType(keyType, valueType, valueContainsNull)`: Represents values
> comprising a set of key-value pairs. The data type of keys is
> described by `keyType` and the data type of values is described by
> `valueType`

You can use `StructType` instead:

```
test_df.withColumn(
    "test",
    F.struct(
        F.col("cola").cast("float").alias("a"),
        F.col("colb").cast("float").alias("b"),
        F.lit("default").alias("key"),
        F.lit("ext").alias("name"),
    )
).printSchema()

#root
#|-- key: string (nullable = true)
#|-- name: string (nullable = true)
#|-- cola: double (nullable = true)
#|-- colb: double (nullable = true)
#|-- test: struct (nullable = false)
#|    |-- a: float (nullable = true)
#|    |-- b: float (nullable = true)
#|    |-- key: string (nullable = false)
#|    |-- name: string (nullable = false)
```